# Problem editing text converted to mesh

Tags: modeling

I have a problem with my text.

When I press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key I can not change the text from "CINEBRICK STUDIOS" to "******* STUDIOS". It just shows like a wireframe. The text was previously converted to a mesh.

I watched the video and imitated everything perfectly. At first everything went well. I could change the text with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. However I want to change it again, which does not work. It was a long time ago when I imitated this video. Original video link (YouTube): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=do0jF3zb5_U

Here are a few pictures of the current situation.

[image: Edit mode]

[image: Cinebrick]

[image: Studios]

[image]

Comment: You can't change the text once it's been converted into a mesh. Please don't create duplicate questions, you can edit your original question and the moderators can re-open it. You can directly attach your images to your question by clicking on the image icon, .blend files can be shared through https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is the wireframe of the mesh when you're switching to edit mode by pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Once you've converted your text object into a mesh you can't edit the text anymore. Since the conversion is not reversible you will have to create a new text object perform the desired changes to the text and then convert it into a mesh.